# Improve performance of SP using string search and Table defined functions.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

The following query fragments have 62% and 31% estimated cost respectively.

```
insert into #Matches (LegalPartyId)
        select top (@MaxRows) LegalPartyId
        from (select LegalPartyId, DisplayName from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (DisplayName LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId, DisplayName from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (LastName LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId, DisplayName from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (PIN LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId, DisplayName from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (AIN LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId, DisplayName from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (CommStreetName LIKE '4450700010%')) lp
        group by LegalPartyId, DisplayName
        order by DisplayName

insert into #OwnedPINs (LegalPartyId, PIN)
        select distinct lpr.LegalPartyId, rtrim(ro.PIN) PIN
        from
          grm_records_AllLegalPartyRoleByEffDate(@EffDate, 'A') lpr
          join grm_records_RevObjByEffDate(@EffDate, null) ro
            on ro.Id = lpr.ObjectId
        where
          lpr.LegalPartyId in (select LegalPartyId from #Matches)
          and lpr.ObjectType = 100002 -- ObjectType.RevObj
          and lpr.LPRoleType = 100701
```

SQL server tuning adviser suggests hat we need to add the following index,

[image]

However all the columns of the index are already part of a non-clustered index.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LegalPartyRole1] ON [dbo].[LegalPartyRole]
    (
    [ObjectId] ASC, [ObjectType] ASC,  [BegEffDate] ASC,  [LPRoleType] ASC, 
    [EffStatus] ASC, [PrimeLegalParty] ASC, [LegalPartyId] ASC, [Id] ASC
    );
```

Is SQL server asking me to reorder the columns of the non-clustered index?

Also SQL sentry is showing me the following message of several "nodes" of the execution plan. Is this because of a heavy use of table defined functions.

[image]

How can I improve the performance of this stored procedure? Please advise.

Comment: Your index has a VERY long key... and the order of columns in a key matters.

Comment: Thanks @pmbAustin. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without more information. You can try to compare the suggested index against the existing index (try with one, then with the other, then with both). Use SET STATISTICS TIME ON before running the query, and SET STATISTICS TIME OFF after.  That helps with comparisons. SET STATISTICS IO ON/OFF also helps you see how much I/O there is. Other than that, you'll have to post the indexes and plan.

Comment: I don't understand why SQL is suggesting an index that includes EffStatus when you don't seem to use EffStatus in your query at all. Unless the actual query you're using is different. EDIT: Never mind, I guess one of your functions must be heavily using it.

Comment: @ZLK: yes that's true, one of my functions is heavily using it. Changing the order of the columns in the non-clustered index(as suggested by @pmbAustin) improved the performance of the SP by 10% but not as much as we are expecting.

Comment: I mean, there's a whole bunch of factors that go into how SQL chooses a query plan and what sort of things you can do to tune it. There's no easy answer here with the information you've provided - the best thing you can do is look at the query plan and see what's costing the most and think about how to improve that (or avoid using that plan), then rinse and repeat.

Comment: You're using a UNION (which does de-duplicating) and then doing a GROUP BY the same fields... would using a UNION ALL (which doesn't filter duplicates) help things at all, and still give you the same results? It's hard to tell without seeing the function and a bunch of other information.

Comment: your query have 2 independant parts. Which part have bad perfomance?

Comment: @MikhailLobanov: The first part is the one that had the worst performance but we were able to improve it by only selecting the data that we required. This in turn caused the system to use an index scan instead of a full table scan. Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to bring down the execution time from 150 seconds to 3 seconds by only selecting the required data. In the query below, we removed the DisplayName since it was not required. The DisplayName was causing a full table scan. If however we selected just the LegalPartyId the system used a index scan.

```
insert into #Matches (LegalPartyId)
        select top (@MaxRows) LegalPartyId
        from (select LegalPartyId from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (DisplayName LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (LastName LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (PIN LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (AIN LIKE '4450700010%')
union select LegalPartyId from GRM_Records_LegalPartySearchable(@EffDate) where (CommStreetName LIKE '4450700010%')) lp
        group by LegalPartyId
        order by LegalPartyId
```